How to detect the vertical distance to the last visible thing?
How to write a macro that sets the actual distance from the last visible thing (could be characters, TikZ objects, images, etc) or the top of page?
Something like:
\newdimen\a\newdimen\b\def\truevskip#1{
\a=#1 \b= <distance from the last visible thing or top of page>
\advance\a by-\b \vskip\a}

Edit: \newdimen location corrected.
It is ok if compiling multiple times is needed.

in general that is not possible

Can you add some background information why you would like to know the distance? Maybe the is some other way.

apart from that \newdimen\a\newdimen\b should be outside the definition otherwise you allocate two registers each time the macro is used, and there is a fixed number of registers (256 in classic tex, 32 thousand in etex)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I just want my theorems in a math paper to be at a fixed distance to whatever comes before it (mainly paragraphs and TikZ diagrams).

@DavidCarlisle I can accept compiling multiple times. If still not possible, is there an ad hoc way for one article? (By redefining everything I use in a specific article.)

the question is not well formed for the tex model, white space is (usually) stretchy so whatever space you add between two items the actual space as appears on the page will depend on items that may be added to the page later. Also tex can not "look back" up the vertical list beyond one item, so while you can see if the previous item was \vskip 2cm you can not tell what is before that. if it was another \vskip for example. You should instead aim to control the white space that is added to the document, not assume arbitrary stuff has been added and then try to interogate what that was,

@DavidCarlisle l3galley ;)
